# Windowbuilder is not working on Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, windowbuilder, eclipse-oxygen

I installed Windowbuilder from this website: https://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/1.9.1/, but it doesn't work on eclipse oxygen.

---

I have no idea how to fix it.
Can someone help me?
I need it fast because of an chalenge with my friend.

I tryed to install it over the marketplace, but there it doesn't exists.

Comment: I don't know where you downloaded Eclipse IDE or _WindowBuilder_, but I recommend going to [eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org). From there you can download both the latest version of the IDE (which, at time of writing, is named 2023-09, version number is 4.29) and the latest version of _WindowBuilder_. For your information, Eclipse Oxygen is version 4.7 and was released in 2017. Nowadays, a new IDE is released every three months, i.e. in March, in June, in September and in December.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Eclipse Marketplace entry for WindowBuilder it is available for Eclipse versions 4.15 and later.  Eclipse Oxygen is 4.7.

If you want to use WindowBuilder you will need to upgrade your Eclipse installation to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the SWT/JFace Java Project, select JavaSE-1.8 as execution environment JRE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).